# Does a slide in a projector act as a diffuser?

Tags: optics, electromagnetic-radiation

I was wondering whether or not a slide in a slide projector acts as light diffuser? So when I have a light source that does not have a parallel beam on the slide can I expect that the other side of the slide is illuminated with a Lambertian of similar reflectance?

I am wondering this because I want to know if I have to raytrace the light path of a projector from the slide (assuming Lambertian reflectance of the slide) or from the light source.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are asking. Are you trying to figure out where to locate the object plane when designing a projector lens?

Comment: In fact the question is as follows: Do I have to raytrace from the light source through the lenses and slide to the screen, or can I assume that I can raytrace from the slide as starting point. So it the object plane the slide or is it the light source?

Comment: Yes, I read the text of the question. In fact, you can ray trace from wherever you want, to wherever you want, and it doesn't matter whether the slide is a diffuser or not. So I was asking for clarification in order to help *you*. But instead I got snarked at. Thanks

Comment: I didn't snark at you? I just wanted to elaborate on my question. But you already provided a clear answer for which I thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The slide will not act as a diffuser, but there will often be a diffusing element upstream near or adjacent to the slide, so treating it as a diffuse source is probably a good approximation.